# Inline <img tag style is being ignored in wordpress genesis

Tags: css, image, inline

I'm using the news-pro genesis theme and I'm having an issue where an inline style on the img tag is being ignored completely.

I can't seem to figure out why on a post its ignoring it but its working on a page.

Here is the code:

```
    <img style="float: right; margin: 0px 0px 20px 20px;" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/hereford_herd.jpg">
```

Its displaying the image full screen instead of floating right. On the page where its being used its displaying correctly.

Suggestions or ideas? I checked the CSS for !important on the img tag and commented out the only ones I saw.

Comment: `Its displaying the image full screen instead of floating right.` That implies that it's full-width and if it is indeed full width, how do you expect it to float in any direction? Further more, does the surrounding HTML and the accompanying CSS allow it to float right? E.G is there enough space?

Comment: Can you see your code in the HTML?

Comment: Yes I can see the code in the html in both the post page and the page where it is working correctly.  When I say full image, its filling the post page but its sized correctly when its displayed on the other page.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the page?

Comment: Check in your browser inspector (F12 in Chrome or right-click, "inspect"), what css properties are given to the image.

Additionally remember, that giving a float property forces most elements to "display: block" https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo